# Function return number if params are number; string if any is not

Tags: typescript

Here is my case:

```
/**
 * Add types to the `add` function, so it:
 * - accepts `a` parameter of type string or number
 * - accepts `b` parameter of type string or number
 * - returns type number when both `a` and `b` are of type number
 * - returns type string when at least one param is of type string
 * 
 * ⚠️ There is no need to modyfy the body of the function.
 */

function add(a,b)  {
    if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number') {
        return a + b;
    }

    return String(a) + String(b);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////   TEST CASES - look but don't modify   ////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const sumA = add(1, 2);
const sumB = add(1, '2');
const sumC = add('1', 2);
const sumD = add('1', '2');

type cases = [
    Expect<Equal<typeof sumA, number>>,
    Expect<Equal<typeof sumB, string>>,
    Expect<Equal<typeof sumC, string>>,
    Expect<Equal<typeof sumD, string>>,
]

type Expect<T extends true> = T
type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false
```

No matter what I do (conditional return, type aliases) it does not allow me to pass through Expect cases.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/PQKhCgAIUhBATekAuBPADgUwM4oPYoAWmkABgIaKmQBmArgHYDGyAlngwDSTYGvIAuKDAC0kckyaZ0yXBWrpyAJ3IBbTMkxLIeGigwlsyJawYBzHdoZ1VAIy3DIYiVJlzbC5Wo1adetFg8xqYWeFY29kqOYkoadEoMuAEk1na+AO7EDJC2eMiEZOTU5AxIpB7isX76gamR0ZCxyPGJNYbB5pCZmNnkyJAANpjkRjoMJIoqqpCsuLptQSbmjo6ABWSA8H+QACrEVbOQDATjmEjIBKp48Kg0qEQkuVfV+ST0zGwcAHTCwODgryzsXqIAAU5E4tgAlJBIABvKDQmZ6YHJebkSAAXkxkAA5HUtNjIAAyQltea2DFY3ERfFQuEI+mNOIJcSQADUOQA3PDoQBfX70potSAAZQ6ZlBUPZoqW4shXL54GASuVKtVavVGs1Wu1OqVit1aoRWwAosKtpAAMKwYWmpyDPB4ADWOTo-XgHGx-Qu8FYNwRBrV+oDwZDoZ14CYHFG2BssAx4hBAEZuAAmCFcyOJfox1QAIXjlHgwOTOJT2PTEaj2ZsFoLIOxiexqYrmejNgAInWiw2m6Xy1zwMlIEwRjh4wBtbmQY0ADywLAAPMaAI50cgDBcovQ52DcPFKAB8B84U9n8+QS9X683BnmOdz3CMMqPJ-pZ8wi5Xa43W54NcfYovqec4fheX7Xr+ObtgBz7HuAAC6vxDu+i7mpgM6aKUSRKHQmAHvGWyDgY05XhuAAa3AAJr4ei8LAguWwHsCULovhaEYT08C4GRkAAPyQImkACJAaaQOhmFcXRDFMSxbFiRxWGQJRfECUJIlQvxxi4WpNDrtgmBAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) will help here:

```
function add(a: number, b: number): number
function add(a: string | number, b: string | number): string
function add(a: string | number, b: string | number): string | number {
    if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number') {
        return a + b;
    }

    return String(a) + String(b);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhBATekAuBPADgUwM4oPYoAWmkABgIaKmQBmArgHYDGyAlngwDSTYGvIAuKDAC0kckyaZ0yXBWrpyAJ3IBbTMkxLIeGigwlsyJawYBzHdoZ1VAIy3DIYiVJlzbC5Wo1adetFg8xqYWeFY29kqOYkoadEoMuAEk1na+AO7EDJC2eMiEZOTU5AxIpB7isX76gamR0ZCxyPGJNYbB5pCZmNnkyJAANpjkRjoMJIoqqpCsuLptQSbmjo6ABWSA8H+QACrEVbOQDATjmEjIBKp48Kg0qEQkuVfV+ST0zGwcAHTCwODgryzsXqIAAU5AEBwiWm4tnBdS0AEpYZCov93kD4KDwUYlhYAD4QtJKaFYjp4gmRRGLEJ-RgAjjiEFgqmdfFwok5Ek4yCs5GU7Ehbnk3wAbygkHFrD0wOS83IkAAvIrIAByNnKyAAMg1bXmtgVStVyOV8MgovF5vNTRa4kgAGocgBuMXigC+vwtVoSkAAyqTQSb7b6ccDbPCnW7wMAo9GY7G4-GE4mk8mU1HI6m4+atgBRb1bSAAYVg3tzTkGeDwAGscnR+vAOMr+hd4JLbuKM3H0x3uz3eynwEwOKNsDZYAqGRiAIzcABMYYHQ-6I9UACFx5Qp9xlTPjU7B4klzYC+uQcrJ8rZ-P98ObAARE8Ys8XlU7+fgZKQJgjHDjgDazsgbMAA8sBYAAebMAEc6HIAYwJlPRl1gbg2QAPlQzgAOA0DkAg6DYPggx5mXFduH5cx0Mwi1sMwcCoJguCEJ4I8yNJSisJA2jcPogimOXW9WJxdiAF1fg-GjwPzTAgM0UokiUOhMFQ8ctnfAxAPwuCAA1uAATWU+UAOBMCtlQ4ETXlZSpJknp4FwLTIAAfkgSdIHBOdIGk2S7KMkyzIsqzPJsuTIF0pyXLcyAPOc4xFMimhYOwTAgA)

Comment: Uh, kind of obvious but yet still not sth that crossed my mind. Thanks Aleksey! <3

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `Overloading` feature of JavaScript here.
Add overloaded definitions of the given function as follows

```
function add(a: number, b: number) : number
function add(a: string | number, b: string | number) : string
function add(a: string | number,b: string |number) : string | number {
        if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number') {
            return a + b;
        }
    return String(a) + String(b);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, it works :) However solution of Aleksey below is a bit more concise and looks a bit nicier. Thanks nevertheless! <3